# Can't able to update Vue template in laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I don't know Vue.js. I have just cloned one project from GitHub and now I want to edit come Vue template code. After updating the class of p tag, I am still getting old class when I refresh the page.

I think I need to re-generate or re-compile like something but don't know how as it's my first time with Vue.js.

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You need to install node modules and their dependencies from package.json stored in root directory of your laravel project: 
Run

```
npm install
```

And then after node modules are installed:

```
npm run dev
```

To compile the assets.

See more about frontend and vue in laravel here: 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/frontend

Comment: So every time I change something in Veu.js while developing I need to run `npm run dev`?

Comment: @ShubhamPatel Yes. Also you can do `npm run watch` to detect changes automatically

Comment: For now i am doing npm install -g windows-build-tools

as npm install giving me bunch or errors

Comment: You should probably need to run in case of windows `npm install --no-bin-links --save-dev`